# DevExpress GridControl, how to make **any** columns that are of type DateTime display in a specific DateTime format?

Tags: wpf, datetime, devexpress, gridcontrol

I databind my `GridControl ItemsSource` to a collection of type `List<Foo>` where `Foo` contains the `DateTime` property `TimeStamp`. I would like to make sure that when `TimeStamp` is rendered on the `GridControl` that it shows in "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff" format.

- How can I specify that particular column given I know the column name and set the format?
- What can I do to have **any** column that is of type `DateTime` rendered in a specific format (such as "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")?

Regarding my first question I have the following, but it does not seem to work:

```
<dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="Sample Data" ItemHeight="2*">
                <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding SampleData}" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True">
                    <dxg:GridControl.View>
                        <dxg:TableView AllowEditing="False" AutoWidth="True" BestFitArea="All" AllowBestFit="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" ShowSearchPanelMode="Always"/>
                    </dxg:GridControl.View>

                    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="TimeStamp">
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings DisplayFormat="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"/>
                        </dxg:GridColumn>
                    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

                </dxg:GridControl>
            </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the first question, you need to use `DateEditSettings`, not `TextEditSettings` like:

```
<dxe:DateEditSettings DisplayFormat="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"/>
```

As for the second question, you can loop through all columns and set the format... something like (untested):

```
foreach (var column in MyGridControl.Columns)
{
  if (column.FieldType == typeof(DateTime))
  {
    column.ActualEditSettings.DisplayFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the second question, where would I specify such if I did not want to specify the `FieldName`? Would I just omit the `FieldName`?

Comment: I actually reversed your questions... the first one is for the specified column (for which you know the name)... the second one is for all columns of `DateTime` type. I'll edit

Comment: Regarding the second question, where would I most optimally loop through all columns? Best to hook up to an event like "OnDataBoundPropertyUpdated" within xaml?

Comment: There's an `AutoGeneratedColumns` event if you want to do it when automatically populating columns (see: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_AutoGeneratedColumnstopic ) or, for older versions of DevExpress, [ColumnsPopulated](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_ColumnsPopulatedtopic). If you are not populating automatically, do it whenever you add the columns manually